# Помогите с node.js

Tags: node.js

Вот код:

```html
const SteamUser = require('steam-user');
const SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');
const SteamCommunity = require('steamcommunity');
const community = new SteamCommunity();
const  client = new SteamUser();
const  steam = new SteamCommunity();
const  TradeOfferManager = require('steam-tradeoffer-manager');
const  manager = new TradeOfferManager({
  "language": "en",
  "pollInterval": 5000
});


SteamCommunity.PrivacyState = {
 "Private": 1,
};

const  logOnOptions = {
 "accountName"   : "john200214", // Bot username
 "password"      : "ZAdd8GZFg", // Bot password
 'twoFactorCode': SteamTotp.generateAuthCode("hupzeGMq/hkU84E5hH/Wwxzlshw=") // shared_secret
};

const  identitySecret = "v3bdrTyNH9nog23mfXkhdACew1o="; // identitySecret


steam.login(logOnOptions, function(err, sessionID, cookies, steamguard) {
 if (err) {
  console.log("[Bot] There was an error logging in! Error details: " + err.message);
  process.exit(1); //terminates program
 } else {
  console.log("[Bot] Successfully logged in as " + logOnOptions.accountName);
  steam.chatLogon();
  manager.setCookies(cookies, function(err) {
   if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
   }
  });
 }
 steam.startConfirmationChecker(20000, identitySecret); //Auto-confirmation enabled!
});

manager.on('newOffer', processTrade);

function processTrade(offer) {
 console.log("[Bot] New trade from " + offer.partner);
 if(offer.itemsToGive.length!=0)
  {
   proceed=false;
   offer.decline(function(err)
   {
    console.log("[Bot] Declined offer from " + offer.partner + ", Trade does not match the settings.");
    if (err)
    {
     console.log("[Bot] Decline error: " + err.message);
    }
   }); 
    return;
    }
    else
   offer.accept(function(err) {
  if (err) {
   console.log("[Bot] Error accepting offer: " + err.message);
  } else {
   console.log("[Bot] Successfully accepted an offer from " + offer.partner);
   community.uploadAvatar('https://trinixy.ru/pics5/20180508/uncommon_01.jpg');
  }
 })
}
```

Ошибка возникает тут:
community.uploadAvatar('https://trinixy.ru/pics5/20180508/uncommon_01.jpg');

Сама ошибка:

```html
[Bot] Successfully logged in as john200214
[Bot] New trade from 76561198906868311
[Bot] Successfully accepted an offer from 76561198906868311
C:\Users\a\node_modules\steamcommunity\components\profile.js:254
                callback(new Error("Not Logged In"));
                ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at SteamCommunity.uploadAvatar (C:\Users\a\node_modules\steamcommunity\components\profile.js:254:3)
    at C:\Users\a\Desktop\d\Donation-Bot.js:68:14
    at update (C:\Users\a\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\classes\TradeOffer.js:532:5)
    at manager.getOffer (C:\Users\a\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\classes\TradeOffer.js:566:3)
    at Helpers.checkNeededDescriptions (C:\Users\a\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\index.js:441:4)
    at Object.exports.checkNeededDescriptions (C:\Users\a\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\helpers.js:90:3)
    at _apiCall (C:\Users\a\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\index.js:435:11)
    at SteamCommunity._community.httpRequest (C:\Users\a\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\webapi.js:61:3)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\a\node_modules\steamcommunity\components\http.js:67:15)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\a\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)

C:\Users\a\Desktop\d>pause
```

Документация - https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steamcommunity/wiki/SteamCommunity#uploadavatarimage-format-callback

Comment: Сразу скажу, никогда не имел дел с этим модулем и могу лишь предположить, судя из ошибки "не залогинен", что нужно сначала залогиниться тем объектом, которым вы загружаете аватар, т.е. `community`. У вас есть метод `steam.login`, а `community.login` нет. Наверное в этом и проблема.

Comment: Надеюсь, пароль в вашем коде - это не настоящий пароль? :О